# Como hacer un test Angular 10 de QueryList<Component>

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, jasmine

No encuentro en internet como hacer un test de lo siguiente, tengo un componente que tiene estas lineas pero no se como hacer un test de estas partes en Angular 10.

```
  @ViewChildren('autoCmpl') childComponents: QueryList<InputAutocompleteComponent>;
```

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.childComponents.changes.subscribe(_ => {
      this.validateButtonForm();
    });
  }

  
  validateButtonForm() {
    const idxElem = this.childComponents.toArray().findIndex((ele: any) => ele.hasError === true);
    const elemRef = document.getElementById('submit_Button');
    if (idxElem !== -1) {
      elemRef.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
      elemRef.classList.add('disabled-button');
    } else {
      elemRef.removeAttribute('disabled');
      elemRef.classList.remove('disabled-button');
    }
  }
```

La parte de Testing de jasmine es esta, cuando lanzo el test incia el componente pero no llega a ejecutar cambios en la app y se queda parado en el ngAfterViewInit:

```js
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        MesDossiersFormComponent,
        ...
      ],
      imports: [
        ...
      ],
      providers: [
        ...
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MesDossiersFormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.performSearchCallback = (t: any) => { };
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should ngAfterViewInit', () => {
    spyOn(component.childComponents, 'changes').and.returnValue(of({}));
    component.ngAfterViewInit();
  })
})
```

Comment: ¿Cómo haces los tests generalmente? Si usas TestBed para instanciar el componente, la query asociada a ViewChild se habrá ejecutado al de crearlo: https://indepth.dev/posts/1184/angular-unit-testing-viewchild

Comment: @PabloLozano normalmente para hacer test uso de la siguiente manera, lo añado arriba por temas de limpieza